# Adding slides to an existing carousel manually

Tags: php, images, homepage

I inherited a website from another designer a while back and it was haphazardly put together then. I have been rebuilding it slowly but have never touched the carousel. Now my client wants to add more images to the carousel and I cannot find where to expand the number of images in the carousel passed 5 images in the dashboard. The only solution I can come up with is to go into the code for the homepage and add in the slides. Would this be a viable solution?

Website is www.sbbl.biz

```
<div style="position: relative;float: left;">
    <ul class="rslides rslides1">

                                    <li id="rslides1_s0" class="" style="display: block; float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1; transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;"><a href="http://www.sbbl.biz/clients/holocaust-history-center-2/" class="image-anchor">1255<img width="992" height="560" src="http://www.sbbl.biz/wp-content/uploads/clientfocus_HHC-copy.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://www.sbbl.biz/wp-content/uploads/clientfocus_HHC-copy.jpg 992w, http://www.sbbl.biz/wp-content/uploads/clientfocus_HHC-copy-300x169.jpg 300w, http://www.sbbl.biz/wp-content/uploads/clientfocus_HHC-copy-768x434.jpg 768w" sizes="(max-width: 992px) 100vw, 992px"></a></li>

                                    <li id="rslides1_s1" style="float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1; display: list-item; transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;" class=""><a href="http://www.sbbl.biz/clients/girl-scouts/" class="image-anchor">2145<img width="992" height="560" src="http://www.sbbl.biz/wp-content/uploads/clientfocus_Girl-Scouts-2-1.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://www.sbbl.biz/wp-content/uploads/clientfocus_Girl-Scouts-2-1.jpg 992w, http://www.sbbl.biz/wp-content/uploads/clientfocus_Girl-Scouts-2-1-300x169.jpg 300w, http://www.sbbl.biz/wp-content/uploads/clientfocus_Girl-Scouts-2-1-768x434.jpg 768w" sizes="(max-width: 992px) 100vw, 992px"></a></li>

                                    <li id="rslides1_s2" style="float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1; display: list-item; transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;" class=""><a href="http://www.sbbl.biz/clients/tucson-jewish-community-center-2/" class="image-anchor">2079<img width="992" height="560" src="http://www.sbbl.biz/wp-content/uploads/clientfocus_JCC-PHASE-3-copy.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://www.sbbl.biz/wp-content/uploads/clientfocus_JCC-PHASE-3-copy.jpg 992w, http://www.sbbl.biz/wp-content/uploads/clientfocus_JCC-PHASE-3-copy-300x169.jpg 300w, http://www.sbbl.biz/wp-content/uploads/clientfocus_JCC-PHASE-3-copy-768x434.jpg 768w" sizes="(max-width: 992px) 100vw, 992px"></a></li>

                                    <li id="rslides1_s3" style="float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1; display: list-item; transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;" class=""><a href="http://www.sbbl.biz/clients/city-park/" class="image-anchor">2072<img width="992" height="560" src="http://www.sbbl.biz/wp-content/uploads/clientfocus_City-Park-2.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://www.sbbl.biz/wp-content/uploads/clientfocus_City-Park-2.jpg 992w, http://www.sbbl.biz/wp-content/uploads/clientfocus_City-Park-2-300x169.jpg 300w, http://www.sbbl.biz/wp-content/uploads/clientfocus_City-Park-2-768x434.jpg 768w" sizes="(max-width: 992px) 100vw, 992px"></a></li>

                                    <li id="rslides1_s4" style="float: left; position: relative; opacity: 1; z-index: 2; display: list-item; transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;" class="rslides1_on"><a href="http://www.sbbl.biz/clients/tucson-jewish-community-center/" class="image-anchor">178<img width="992" height="560" src="http://www.sbbl.biz/wp-content/uploads/clientfocus_JCC2.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://www.sbbl.biz/wp-content/uploads/clientfocus_JCC2.jpg 992w, http://www.sbbl.biz/wp-content/uploads/clientfocus_JCC2-300x169.jpg 300w, http://www.sbbl.biz/wp-content/uploads/clientfocus_JCC2-768x434.jpg 768w" sizes="(max-width: 992px) 100vw, 992px"></a></li>
                    </ul><a href="#" class="rslides_nav rslides1_nav prev">Previous</a><a href="#" class="rslides_nav rslides1_nav next">Next</a>
    </div>
```

Screenshot of carousel:

[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance for any knowledge.

Comment: Can you please post the code for the carousel feature in your WordPress theme. You mentioned the dashboard in regards to the images. Can you be more specific? Screenshot would probably help.

Comment: Code and screenshot added above. :-)

Answer (score 0):

No it would not be a viable solution. Never hard-code content like that.

Assuming you have a slider, you should create a custom post type (or use a plugin like [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) to create a repeater field.

Then you'd query a loop of either said posts or fields, and create the appropriate html markup. That way the slides are editable via wp-admin.

Hope that helps.